# Wrong operation index in execute batch exception

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-storage

I am getting an operation index that is out of bounds of the array when executing a batch operation on Windows Azure Tables.

### Exception

> Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Unexpected response code for operation : 0
>     at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result)
>   Request Information
>   RequestID:e31dbcbc-8dc2-46ba-b096-9872b34072cb
>   RequestDate:Sun, 15 Sep 2013 10:41:10 GMT
>   StatusMessage:Accepted
>   ErrorCode:InvalidInput
>   ErrorMessage= 68:One of the request inputs is not valid.
>   batchOperation.Count= 68

As you can see from the error message above, the failed operation index is 68 (zero based) while the total count of operations in the batch is 68 (so the maximum index is 67).

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you provide more details like what version of storage client library (it's 2.0, that's for sure) are you using. What kind of application is it?

Comment: I am using version 2.0 library.

Comment: Well...according to this article, Storage Exceptions are not reliable in the first place.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375374(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Can you provide the exact version, in the first release there was an issue where the index parsing was incorrect and would always point to the zeroth item.  I would recommend upgrading to 2.0.6.1 (or even 2.1 which includes task, iqueryable etc).  Essentially this error is occurring because one entity inside the batch caused an error and therefore the entire batch failed atomically. The index will point to the item which caused the fault. A common error is when clients attempt to persist out of range DateTime objects ( just as minvalue etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another error with leaking ports which I had to upgrade the WindowsAzure.Storage API to version 2.1.0.0. Since I upgraded to this version I cannot see the inconsistent operation index in the batch exception errors.